# For each row of the matrix, find the minimum element and write them into a one-dimensional array

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wrote a code to find "each row of a matrix find the minimum element and write them into a one-dimensional array". But the problem is that I call the "search_min" function, it swears "too few arguments in the function" and "the type argument (int ) is incompatible with the type parameter (int*)"
What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int search_min(int* arr, int size) {
    int min = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i]; 
        }  
    }
    return min;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");

    int n, m, z[100][100];
    cout << " Enter the size of the matrix: ""\n";
    cin >> n >> m;

    cout << " Fill in the matrix: ""\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cin >> z[i][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "The introduced matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << z[i][j] << " "; 
           
        } 
         cout << endl;
       
    }

    cout << "The minimum element of each row of the matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << search_min(z[i][j]);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ```int search_min(int* arr, int size)``` 2 arguments expected but ```search_min(z[i][j]);``` only one given.
Besides ```z[i][j]``` is an ```int```, not an ```int*```.

Comment: and how to solve the eu problem ?

Comment: If I understand your code, maybe ```search_min(z[i],100);``` (searching the min of ith line of length 100).

Comment: Offtopic: This `rus` is not valid locale name on any platform. Maybe you like to use: `ru_RU.utf-8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proposed fix.
You need also to make a simple loop.
for testing on godbolt I removed the cin. You can add them back.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int search_min(int* arr, int size) {
    int min = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] < min) {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return min;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "rus");

    int n = 10;
    int m = 10;
    int z[100][100];
    cout << " Enter the size of the matrix: "
            "\n";
    // cin >> n >> m;

    cout << " Fill in the matrix: "
            "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            z[i][j] = i - j;  // just to test
        }
    }

    cout << "The introduced matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout << z[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << "The minimum element of each row of the matrix:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << search_min(z[i], m);
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/v4xE3vnWT)